# Как добавить иконки в ListViewItem

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу написать что-то вроде простенького FTP клиента. В процессе оформления появился вопрос:

Как перед текстом в ListViewItem поместить иконку папки или файла?

Comment: Поделитесь своим кодом и мы вам поможем

Comment: Какая используется технология? WPF или WinForm?

Comment: Я использую WinForm.

Comment: @Darrio, ну тогда, посмотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете WinForm, то при генерации списка файлов, можно использовать метод `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon` [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). И дальше, добавлять параметры к `ListView`.

Что то вроде этого:

```
 DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"С:\");
 FileInfo[] files=d.GetFiles("*.*");
 ImageList images = new ImageList();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.GetLength(0); i++)
                images.Images.Add(files[i].Extension, (Icon)Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(files[i].FullName));
            listView1.LargeImageList = images;
            listView1.SmallImageList = images;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.GetLength(0); i++)
                listView1.Items.Add(files[i].FullName, images.Images.IndexOfKey(files[i].Extension));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте ListView.ItemTemplate. Пример кода:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <WrapPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="Name: " />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
             <TextBlock Text=", " />
             <TextBlock Text="Age: " />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" FontWeight="Bold" />
             <TextBlock Text=" (" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mail}" TextDecorations="Underline" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" />
             <TextBlock Text=")" />
         </WrapPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Соответственно, в `DataTemplate` можно вставить абсолютно любой контрол с содержимым, будь то картинка или текст